# PYTHON - looping the argument that have multiple information with same starts and ends

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've tried to find this solution but unable to get the correct answer. 
I want it to display all the id inside the text file.

**This is my data in a file**

```
sep 
id_775435
sep
tmane_information
site_area
sep
id_123123123
sep
```

I've had try one example also from stackoverflow...

```
with open('C:/JIR File/A.txt') as input_data:
for line in input_data:
    if line.strip() == 'sep':  
        break

for line in input_data:  
    if line.strip() == 'sep':
        break
    print (line)
```

> Output
>   : id_775435

My concern is to display both of the visual id and maybe more than one with the same special characteristic.

> Output :
>
> ```
>        id_775435
>        id_123123123
> ```

Hope you guys can understand it. 
Thanks for helping in advanced.

Comment: For those who downvotes my question. I will appreciate it if you guys be pleased to comment here, whats wrong with my question so I can do it better next time. Thank you. Respect and give a chance to a new person to learn from you guys :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help :

```
with open('C:/JIR File/A.txt', 'r') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:  
        if line.startswith('id_'):
            print line[3:].rstrip() # this will remove 'id_' & extra newline
```

Comment: hi thanks, this is exactly what I want. But any good way if I only want to display the id number, which is now displayed -- id_775435 -- I want it to display only 775435

Comment: sorry I can't vote it because rejected by stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will accept it as the answer because you are the first answered my additional question :D

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in input_data:  
    if line.startswith('id_'):
        print (line)
```

`startswith()` is a better way to do your job.

Comment: hi thanks, this is exactly what I want. But any good way if I only want to display the id number, which is now displayed -- id_775435 -- I want it to display only 775435

Comment: sorry I can't vote it because rejected by stackoverflow.

Comment: You can't vote it because you have to have at least 25 reputation to vote on a question or answer. Although if this answer helped you then you can accept it. @loki

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Okay... then how to accept it. Sorry, im new in stack.

Comment: You can see a checkmark below the answer upvote downvote button. Click on that it will turn to green which means you accepted the answer

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Thanks a lot, :D Appreciate it.

Comment: @loki `print(line[3:])` would solve it. Learning to slice is a very import skill in Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print lines that contain `'id_'` you can easily check with `if 'id_' in line:`

Or to check if the line starts with `'id_'` you can do `if line[0:3] == 'id_':`

Comment: hi thanks, this is exactly what I want.  But any good way if I only want to display the id number, which is now displayed -- id_775435 -- I want it to display only 775435

Comment: sorry I can't vote it because rejected by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.startswith:

```
file = ["sep", "id_775435", "sep", "tmane_information", "site_area", "sep", "id_123123123", "sep"]

for line in file:
  if line.startswith( 'id_' ):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
id_775435
id_123123123
```

Comment: hi thanks, this is exactly what I want. But any good way if I only want to display the id number, which is now displayed -- id_775435 -- I want it to display only 775435

Comment: sorry I can't vote it because rejected by stackoverflow.